# python - change tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, scope

The following script creates a tkinter window with a text label, exit button and change-text button:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        test_label = Label(root, text="none").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        change_text_btn = Button(root, text="change_text", command=self.set_label_text).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        exit_btn = Button(root, text="Exit", command=self.client_exit).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

    def set_label_text(self):
        test_label.config(text='changed the value')

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

After click on `change_text_btn` I get a `NameError: name 'test_label' is not defined` error. So the problem is that `test_label` created in `init_window()` is not avaliable from `set_label_text()` beacuse of the scope. How do I fix it?

Comment: Could you indent the `set_label_text` function to make it apart of `init_window?`

Comment: Just indenting it - doesent work;

indenting and changing like this:
`def set_label_text(self):  
            self.test_label.config(text='changed the value')`
doesen't work;

indenting and changing like this:
`def set_label_text():  
            test_label.config(text='changed the value')`
doesen't work as well;

in all cases I get `'Window' object has no attribute 'set_label_text'` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overcome the issue, you can make `test_label` an instance variable by prefixing it with `self`. Besides that, when you chain methods like that, what happens is you assign `None` to your variable, since `grid()` returns `None` - instead, place each method in a separate line (this stands for all of your buttons):

```
self.test_label = Label(root, text="none")
self.test_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Of course, you'd need to refer to it with `self.test_label` later on in your `set_label_text` function.

Other than that, I suggest you get rid of `from tkinter import *`, since you don't know what names that imports. It can replace names you imported earlier, and it makes it very difficult to see where names in your program are supposed to come from. Use `import tkinter as tk` instead.